# ASP.NET MVC Refresh Control from Model After Ajax Form Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Sorry if I am missing something obvious as I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

As shown in the code sample below, I have Kendo Textbox and Multiselect controls inside a partial view. When "change" event of Textbox is fired I am posting the form and trying to Rebind Kendo Multiselect control to Model.

Multiselect control binds to the Model on the intial load but after the ajax call it does not rebind/refresh to reflect the changes in the model.

Can anybody help with where I might be going wrong?

Please see code sample below:

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model MVCTest20.Models.Config
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#SalesOrder').on("change", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Index',
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<form>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_SOLookup", Model);}
</form>
```

**_SOLookup.cshtml**

```
<p><strong>Sales Order / Project</strong></p>
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
      .Name("SalesOrder")) <div id="sales-order-arrow" class="help_arrow"></div>

<p><strong>Line Item</strong></p>

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("LineItems")
      .Placeholder("Select Line(s)")
      .HtmlAttributes(new {@class= "cb-create-control" })

      .DataTextField("Name")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .BindTo(Model.LineItemCollection))
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private static Config config;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (config == null)
        {
            config = new Config();
        }

        config.LineItemCollection = new LineItem[]
        {
            new LineItem {Name = "500.1 - FAS8060AE - 001 - R6", Id = "700"}
        }.ToList();

        return View(config);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Config data)
    {
        data.LineItemCollection = new LineItem[]
        {
            new LineItem {Name = "1.1 - FAS8060AE - 001 - R6", Id = "100"},
            new LineItem {Name = "3.1 - FAS8060AE - 001 - R6", Id = "200"},
            new LineItem {Name = "6.1 - FAS8060AE - 001 - R6", Id = "300"}
        }.ToList(); 

        return View(data);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Config
    {
        public Config()
        {

            LineItemCollection = new List<LineItem>();

        }
        private string _salesorder;
        public string SalesOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return _salesorder;
            }
            set
            {
                _salesorder = value;
            }
        }
        public string LineItems { get; set; }
        public List<LineItem> LineItemCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The `MultiSelect` method eventually render the HTML markup . In your ajax call's `success` or `done` event, you need to update the DOM with the response coming back.

Comment: I added following to ajax call:
                success: function(data) {$('body').append(data);}
but now I end up with two instances of the Multiselect.

Comment: Your appending it to the body so that is to be expected. Sounds like you really want to replace the existing partial. If that is the case, your controller action should return the partial view - not the index view and you should append to form, not body: `$('form').append(data);` You may need to wrap your partial in a div with an id and use .html() instead of .append()